# I need help with this breadboard

Tags: breadboard

[image: Breadboard]

Let me say to set the scene, that I am a complete beginner with electronics, not having done anything since my school days.  I can write code, but hardware is another thing entirely.

I got myself an Arduino, and bought a breadboard from Maplins. The only thing is, the layout is very different to what I see on most tutorials, and I don't want to risk damaging anything.

**Can anyone link to any tutorial which uses this breadboard layout?**

Comment: The use of meta tags is discouraged. http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/115/2118

Comment: Fair enough - that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Connections would be wired together as such:[image]

EDIT: I am not sure about the bottom connections. can someone confirm?

Comment: Dean said "Then the part at the bottom is the same Row A 1-30 are connected and so on to F 1-30." I interpreted that to mean the busses run perpendicular to your drawing.  But, I don't own it, so I can't verify it.  Perhaps we should add something to the answer to help determine how to verify the layout of a breadboard?

Answer (score 3):

I have one of these breadborads. Row 1 A-F are connected(horizontally) this is the same all the way down to 28(not connected vertically). Then 1 G-L are connected. In the picture below I have a 555 AStable. Notice I put it across the gap this is because there not connected. Also the voltage rails are easy to read the length of the line shows the length of the rail. Then the part at the bottom is the same Row A 1-30 are connected and so on to F 1-30. 
[image: Similar Breadboard]